# Welcome to Nginx page displays instead of actual webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, unicorn

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project on an Ubuntu server. Whenever I try and access the app, I am always greeted with:

> Welcome to nginx!
>
> If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

Here is my code from the "sites_enabled" directory:

```
pstream unicorn_site {
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.site.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;

    error_page 500 502 504 /500.html;
    error_page 503 @503;

    server_name http://[ip_address];
    root /data/site/current/public;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn_site;

    location @unicorn_site {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_pass http://unicorn_site;
        # limit_req zone=one;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/site.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/site.error.log;
    }

    location ^~ /assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    location = /50x.html {
        root html;
    }

    location = /404.html {
        root html;
    }

    location @503 {
        error_page 405 = /system/maintenance.html;
        if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
        }
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
    }

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|PATCH|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS)){
        return 405;
    }

    if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
        return 503;
    }
}
```

I am not sure what the problem is as the app seems to have everything it need to be working correctly. I can provide any part of the code anyone needs. Help is much appreciated.

EDIT: I am also always getting this error when I attempt to load the page:

> 2018/06/15 15:39:10 [warn] 15280#0: server name "http://[ip_address]" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site:14

EDIT 2: Here is nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move 'try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn_site;' under location /

```
location / {
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn_site;
}
```

Comment: Same result :/ 
and any error that comes back is always the same 
2018/06/15 15:39:10 [warn] 15280#0: server name "http://[ip_address]" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site:17

Answer (score 0):

The `server_name http://[ip_address];` looks wrong. try `server_name example.com`

Comment: Im using the ip address from an EC2 instance, so using the website name didn't work unfortunately

Comment: The `http://` is wrong, see the documentation https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: I've changed it to my Public DNS from EC2 without http:// and i am still getting the welcome screen

Comment: can you add your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf to the question? might be you are not including the sites-enabled directory like so `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` (in the `http` section

Comment: the file in `sites-enabled` ends with `.conf`? Just checking every possibility.

Comment: the terminal shows it without .conf at the end, just as "site"
There are no files in nginx/conf.d if that means anything

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured ruby_passenger line ?

Follow this carefully and your deployment should be successful

Choose your ubuntu version there and proceed

https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04